# Is it valid to rebind a variable in a while loop?

Tags: while-loop, rust, slice

Is it valid to rebind a mutable variable in a while loop?  I am having trouble getting the following trivial parser code to work.  My intention is to replace the newslice binding with a progressively shorter slice as I copy characters out of the front of the array.

```
/// Test if a char is an ASCII digit
fn is_digit(c:u8) -> bool {
    match c {
        30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39 => true,
        _ => false
    }
}

/// Parse an integer from the front of an ascii string,
/// and return it along with the remainder of the string
fn parse_int(s:&[u8]) -> (u32, &[u8]) {
    use std::str;
    assert!(s.len()>0);
    let mut newslice = s; // bytecopy of the fat pointer?
    let mut n:Vec<u8> = vec![];

    // Pull the leading digits into a separate array
    while newslice.len()>0 && is_digit(newslice[0])
    {
        n.push(newslice[0]);
        newslice = newslice.slice(1,newslice.len()-1);
        //newslice = newslice[1..];
    }

    match from_str::<u32>(str::from_utf8(newslice).unwrap()) {
        Some(i) => (i,newslice),
        None => panic!("Could not convert string to int.  Corrupted pgm file?"),
    }
}

fn main(){
            let s:&[u8] = b"12345";
            assert!(s.len()==5);
            let (i,newslice) = parse_int(s);
            assert!(i==12345);
            println!("length of returned slice: {}",newslice.len());
            assert!(newslice.len()==0);
}
```

parse_int is failing to return a slice that is smaller than the one I passed in:

```
length of returned slice: 5
task '<main>' panicked at 'assertion failed: newslice.len() == 0', <anon>:37
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

[Run this code in the rust playpen](http://is.gd/hep11z)

Comment: `is_digit` could be written `c >= b'0' && c <= b'9'`, incidentally.

Comment: Right, I"m expecting this entire chunk of code to be obsoleted by the standard library if it hasn't been already.  I'm learning, and avoiding external dependencies like the plague until 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [As Chris Morgan mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27237862/234590), your call to `slice` passes the wrong value for the `end` parameter. `newslice.slice_from(1)` yields the correct slice.
2. `is_digit` tests for the wrong byte values. You meant to write `0x30`, etc. instead of `30`.
3. You call `str::from_utf8` on the wrong value. You meant to call it on `n.as_slice()` rather than `newslice`.

Answer (score 1):

Rebinding variables like that is perfectly fine. The general rule is simple: if the compiler doesn’t complain, it’s OK.

It’s a very simple error that you’ve made: your slice end point is incorrect.

`slice` produces the interval [start, end)—a half-open range, not closed. Therefore when you wish to just remove the first character, you should be writing `newslice.slice(1, newslice.len())`, not `newslice.slice(1, newslice.len() - 1)`. You could also write `newslice.slice_from(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Chris, but making that change doesn't seem to affect the behavior... http://is.gd/rBIMNF

Comment: So either I have some other newb mistake in there, or perhaps the compiler isn't handling the anonymous tuple I'm constructing from inside the match statement?

Comment: Thanks!  But oh man, is that trio of mistakes embarrassing.  Those all came in during refactoring to get code to pass the compiler, but still...  Think I should delete the question?  Or leave it in case someone searches on some piece of the code that happens to be correct?